# Returning the list in the flutter receiving empty list

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<dynamic> allDataList = [];
 Future<void> compareUserBids() async {
final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection("Pro-$productName-$productId")
    .getDocuments();
List<DocumentSnapshot> templist;
templist = snapshot.documents;
allDataList = templist.map((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  return {ds.documentID: ds.data};
}).toList();
 return allDataList;
```

}

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  compareUserBids(); 
  print(allDataList);
}
```

When i am tying to print this data it is printing the null values but after hot reload it is printing the values

Comment: Where do you call `compareUserBids` function? Can you add more code?

Comment: Sorry by mistake i forgot to add that code

Comment: posting source code that all defined in one single main.dart would be great for any one to help you easily. Also add expected and actual output.

Comment: Assuming you are using `StatefulWidget`, you need to call `setState` function when you are updating the `allDataList` variable. I can help more if you post your whole code

Comment: Are you on discord or whatsapp  where i can send the whole file

Comment: You can put your code here

Comment: it is a very big code above 300 lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting an empty list is that you've not updated your widget after adding data into your global list.
You should either add the data either inside **setState** or you can call **setState** once before returning your list.

```
 setState((){
   allDataList = templist.map((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
     return {ds.documentID: ds.data};
     },
    ).toList()
   },
 );
```